# Without using L'hopital rule $\lim_{x \to \pi/2 }\frac{\cos3x}{1+\cos2x}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Could you help me please with limit solving without using L'hopital rule
$\lim_{x \to \pi/2 }\frac{\cos3x}{1+\cos2x}$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A two-sided limit does not exist!

Comment: Use trigonometric formulae to reduce everything to functions of x.

Comment: What's with all of the questions about computing various limits without l'Hopital's rule? Is that a standard type of precalculus or calculus exercise?

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\cos 3x}{1+\cos 2x}=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{4\cos^3 x-3\cos x}{1+2\cos^2x-1}=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{4\cos^2 x-3}{2\cos x}=-\frac32\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{1}{\cos x}=diverges$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint :replacing $t=x-\pi/2$ and then you can use the formula's Taylor

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\lim_{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^+}\space\frac{\cos(3x)}{1+\cos(2x)}=\lim_{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^+}\space\frac{\cos(3x)\sec^2(x)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^+}\left(\cos(3x)\sec^2(x)\right)$$

Comment: @Lilly You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\cos 3x}{1+\cos 2x}$$$$=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{4\cos^3x-3\cos x}{2\cos^ 2x}$$$$=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{4\cos^2x-3}{2\cos x}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

$\bullet$ $1+\cos 2x=?$

$\bullet$ $\cos 3x=?$

Comment: i tried this, but it's still remain(0/0)

Comment: @Lilly The hint wants you to write those cosines in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.